# MongoDB: Cleanly query an object by _id with JavaDriver

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to update a Mongo objet using is _id. However i don't find the proper syntax to make it work using JavaDriver, here is what I last try.

`BasicDBObject filtre = new BasicDBObject ("_id", new BasicDBObject("$oid", id_message));`

then giving to the coll.update method. 
I manage to make my request work from the shh but didn't manage to trasnlate it properly to Java.
(request is something like : `db.message.find({"_id" : ObjectId("516a94c4e4b0a315396e4ba3")});` )
`
How do i properly traslate it to Java. (eventually using QueryBuilder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to translate:

```
db.message.find({"_id" : ObjectId("516a94c4e4b0a315396e4ba3")})
```

to Java, follow this basic pattern:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("testDB");
DBCollection messages= db.getCollection("message");
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", new ObjectId("516a94c4e4b0a315396e4ba3"));
DBObject messageDoc = messages.findOne(query);
```

The result would be stored in `messageDoc`.

The [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/#getting-started-with-java-driver) for some reason doesn't cover this basic pattern for some reason currently.